# Dynamic CollectionView cell height depending on textview height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How I can dynamically change collectionviewcell depending on textview height.
   [as you see there is extra space in the second textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pf6u.png)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {


   let statusText = statussText[indexPath.item]


       let rect = NSString(string: statusText).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(293, 155), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)

       let knownHeight: CGFloat = 113//44 + 4 + 4 + 200 + 8 + 24 + 8 + 44

       return CGSizeMake(293, rect.height + knownHeight + 110)//74 + 67 + 50)//+ knownHeight + 100)
```

}

This is my code.

UPDATE

I have solve the issue with the tableview. It is much less customizable than collectionview.

Comment: You really need collection view? Because your collection has only one column, you can use table view instead.

Comment: Have you looked at other posts on SO about this? There are lots of them. Did all of the other solutions not work for you?

Comment: Yeah. It is just prototype of my actual collectionview cell. It is much more complicated than that. So i need to figure it out for the simple one and then do the same for the complex one

Comment: @Losiowaty I coultn`t manage to do it. I have tried all of the solutions almost which i have found.